# Can't import TypeScript library bundled with WebPack

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-3

In a TypeScript project, I am trying to import a TypeScript library named "fsaa-util" that I bundled with WebPack. The code compiles fines but at runtime when trying to use an object from that library they're undefined.

index.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from "fsaa-util";

let t = new MyClass(); //Throws MyClass is not a constructor.
console.log(t);
```

index.ts of the library:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

export { default as MyClass } from "MyClass";
```

MyClass.ts:

```
export default class MyClass {

}
```

tsconfig.json of the library:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "strict": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "plugins": [
            { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
            { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Webpack.config.js of the library:

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                    compiler: 'ttypescript'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.vue', '.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', 'css'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        modules: ["src", "node_modules"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Isn't "export { default as MyClass }" a named export?

Comment: Add a constructor to that class.

Comment: I have tried and will not change anything. A constructor is not needed, classes have a default constructor set.

Comment: I believe this is more a WebPack module resolution issue

Answer (score 0):

Had to add these lines in "output" section of `webpack.config.js` of the library:

```
library: "fsaa-util",
libraryTarget: 'umd',
umdNamedDefine: true
```